# Saving data of all tabs

Tags: android, android-sqlite

application is about to save data from all tabs with button present on toolbar....

button store data to create a user profile

I have tested my database....working fine ..still getting following NullPointerException

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PROFILE extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText   etname,etdate,etmarital_status,etcity,etemail,etaddress,etqualification,
    etobjective,etproject,etachievement,etwork;
    Button svbtn;
    String name;
    String date;
    String marital_status;
    String city;
    String email;
    String address;
    String qualification;
    String objective;
    String project;
    String  achievement;
    String work;
    Context ctx = this;
    Context CTX = this;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
         toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        etname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        etdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dob);
        etmarital_status = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ms);
        etcity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.city);
        etemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        etaddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
        etqualification = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qualification);
        etobjective = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.objective);
        etproject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.project);
        etachievement = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.achevement);
        etwork = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.work);
        svbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

        //button to save data of all tabs
        svbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // converting EditText data to string
                name = etname.getText().toString();
                city = etcity.getText().toString();
                email = etemail.getText().toString();
                address = etaddress.getText().toString();
                qualification = etqualification.getText().toString();
                objective = etobjective.getText().toString();
                project = etproject.getText().toString();
                achievement = etachievement.getText().toString();
                work = etwork.getText().toString();
                marital_status = etmarital_status.toString();

                //calling database DatabaseHandler
                DatabaseHandler handler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                handler.putInformation(handler,name,date,marital_status,city,email,address,objective,project,achievement,work);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
             adapter.addFragment(new INFORMATION(), "GENERAL");
        adapter.addFragment(new QUALIFICATION(), "QUALIFICATION");

        adapter.addFragment(new OBJECTIVE(), "OBJECTIVE");

        adapter.addFragment(new PROJECTS(), "PROJECTS");

        adapter.addFragment(new ACHIEVEMENTS(), "ACHIEVEMENTS");

        adapter.addFragment(new WORK(), "WORK");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }
    }
}
```

Error logs:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
             Process: com.example.vikas.renaz, PID: 17785
             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                 at com.example.vikas.renaz.PROFILE$1.onClick(PROFILE.java:68)
                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: may be you are not getting the `Edittext` element `etname`. show us your xml code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see your "activity_profile.xml". But I guess you put your EditText(s) on each Fragment by separate layout files for each fragment. In that case, you should find EditText(s) in each fragment, not in the Activity, because the "onCreateView" method will not be called unless you select the tab, so you will get "null" value when you find that views on the activity.

Comment: Instead of looking up the EditTexts in the Activity I personally would let each of the fragments return values they represent, including handling the case when the fragment was not shown. The code would look much cleaner, easier to maintain and exchangeable. But thats just my 2 cents.